# disallowed_useragent error on "Sign in with Google"

Tags: ios, authentication, google-oauth, user-agent

I set up "Sign in with Google" on my website and everything works as expected on mobile and web.

One user with iOS had a problem, though. He got a `disallowed_useragent` response and sent me the screenshots I attached to the question.

When we asked their user agent, they gave me this: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1` (Safari 15.6 on iOS 15.6).

I tried to put it in my browser, but the authentication went through as expected.

What I suspect is that they clicked on a link from Outlook (see first screenshot, top left), that opened an embedded browser that Google didn't like. Can this be a good explanation? If that was the case, is there a way around it?

[image]
[image]

*Note, I didn't implement "Sign in with Google" with the chromium embedded framework, whatever that is.*